# Prior Art Request for US 2010/0238293 A1 (Sony) -- on-screen display of television power consumption

Tags: prior-art-request, us20100238293

US Patent Application 12/408623 (pre-grant publication US 2010/0238293 A1) is drawn to an on-screen display of real-time power consumption for a television.

(Technically, the first independent claim is drawn to an on-screen display of power consumption for any electronic device, but the dependent claims and other independent claim(s) are explicit about the television aspect.)

I have been unable to find any useful prior art in this case. The effective filing date (date to beat) is March 20, 2009.

Claim 1 is reproduced below:

A graphical power meter, comprising:

means for measuring, in real time, an internal power consumption value corresponding to power being consumed by an electronic device under at least one operational mode; and

means for displaying a graphical representation of the real-time internal power consumption value from the measuring means to at least one consumer.

Claim 21 is also reproduced below:

A graphical power meter, as recited in claim 1,
wherein the electronic device comprises at least one feature selected from a group consisting essentially of an audio feature and a visual feature,
wherein the electronic device comprises a television,
wherein the measuring means comprises a measurement device adapted for use with a measurement technique,
wherein the measurement technique is adapted for use with a set-top box,
wherein the displaying means comprises a graphic user interface,
wherein the graphic user interface comprises:
at least one input feature; and
at least one output feature,
wherein the at least one input feature comprises at least one feature selected from a group consisting essentially of a window for facilitating entry of user-preset parameters and at least one slider feature,
wherein the at least one output feature comprises at least one feature selected from a group consisting essentially of a visual indication, an audible indication, and an olfactory-perceivable indication,
wherein the visual indication comprises at least one feature selected from a group consisting essentially of a dial, a numerical dial, a dial coupled with units of measure, a bar-graph, a bar-graph coupled with numerical data, a bar-graph coupled with units of measure, a dual-axis graph, and a triple-axis graph,
wherein the audible indication comprises at least one feature selected from a group consisting essentially of a beeping sound, a speech output, an adjustable sound adaptable for the hearing-impaired, a sound being in conformance with a hearing-assistive technology, a sound in conformance with at least one federally-regulated telecommunication and rehabilitation requirement,
wherein the speech output comprises at least one informational element selected from a group consisting essentially of a real-time internal energy consumption value and setup information,
wherein the olfactory-perceivable indication comprises at least one element selected from a group consisting essentially of a pleasant natural scent, a “green” scent, a pleasant scent, a consumer-selected scent,
wherein the at least one output feature facilitates adjusting the internal power consumption using at least one consumer preference,
wherein the at least one consumer preference comprises at least one parameter selected from a group consisting essentially of brightness, contrast, color, saturation level, a backlight level, video rendering style, and audio playback levels,
wherein the video rendering style comprises at least one element selected from a group consisting essentially of a vivid display, a cinema display, and a standard display,
wherein the electronic device undergoes an in-store demonstration,
wherein the measuring means is disposed in a manner selected from a group consisting essentially of a primary side of a power supply and a secondary side of a power supply,
wherein a current sensing circuitry switches-off the power supply if a secondary load exceeds a predetermined threshold,
wherein a current sensing circuitry is applied to at least one output on the secondary side, a summation of the power supplied by the at least one output determining a total output power, the summation being made by at least one element selected from a group consisting essentially of a circuit and a processing unit monitor, the total output power being further determined by an input power consumption level, and the input power consumption level being determined by a power conversion efficiency of the power supply,
wherein displaying means comprises an on-screen display,
wherein the displaying means further includes at least one element selected from a group consisting essentially of a feature for facilitating selection of a visual indication feature and a feature for facilitating selection of at least one energy-saving preference,
wherein the at least one consumer is encouraged to operate the electronic device in an environmentally-conscious energy-saving manner,
wherein the at least one consumer participates in an overall management of a carbon footprint of the electronic device, and
wherein the at least one energy-saving preference is a function of at least one element selected from a group consisting essentially of a user's actively-selected preference, a user's need, a user's budget, a setting inherent to the electronic device, and a viewing environment.

Google Link: https://www.google.com/patents/US20100238293

Comment: US 2010/0122102 A1 seems pretty similar, but it's just shy of being prior art under pre-AIA rules.

Comment: Is a Prius an electronic device?

Comment: There are a number of devices (Prius or any plug-in device with a Kill-A-Watt attached) that technically fulfill the requirements of the first independent claim, but the specification and dependent claims (and independent claim 21) really put the focus on a television (or computer monitor) that displays its own real-time power consumption. I'd like to find prior art that applies to such, rather than just tackling the broadest independent claim.

Comment: Makes sense. Claim 21 is one of the longest claims I've seen and a long claim isn't good for the applicant.

Answer (score 2):

[Intel PowerTop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP) was released in 2007. Amongst other things, it displays the current power usage of a laptop. Moreover, there have been numerous “power monitor” utilities on laptop computers and cellphones over the years. My (post 2009) cellphone displays realtime power use, so an analogous power monitor app on a pre-2009 cell phone (such as an iPhone 3G or earlier) would also demonstrate prior art.

Comment: After some digging into older articles and changelogs for PowerTop, it appears that overall power usage and display usage were only implemented in PowerTop 2.0 from 2012. The orginal PowerTop (at least versions 1.0 through 1.13) did not measure or display this information. The iPhone also did not have any such power display apps prior to 2009 as best as I can determine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell -- claim 1 describes a [energy monitor](https://www.google.com/search?q=energy%20monitor) which is just a specialized form of an [amp-meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-meter) they have been available on the market for as long as I can remember -- the fact that energy monitors have their own LCD to display the energy consumption should probably be irrelevant as claim 1 does not make that distinction.  Claim 21 is a dependent claim (citing claim 1), so if claim 1 is excluded then claim 21 would also be excluded.

The wikipedia page for "[Kill-a-watt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt)" has reference material dated from at least 2005.

Comment: That's not how dependent claims work. For claim 21 to be rejected, all of the limitations of the dependent claim must be found in addition to the limitations of the independent claim.